# TFS Cloud Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio-2015, team-foundation-server, versionamento

Tenho dois projetos no TFS, um banco de dados e uma aplicação. Estou usando a pouco tempo o TFS e tenho dúvidas a respeito das opções *Get Latest Version (Recursive)*, *Check Out for Edit* e *Shelve Pending Changes*.

Imagem: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A opção *Get Latest Version (Recursive)* pelo que observei até agora faz o download da última versão de todas a pastas e subpastas do projeto. Estou com duvida em relação ao *Check Out for Edit* e *Shelve Pending Changes.*

Alguém que já utilize o TFS poderia me esclarecer esta questão ?

Comment: @TobyMosque, muito obrigado, para efetuar teste na aplicação você usa o TFS Express ou o Cloud ?

Comment: @TobyMosque Pode virar uma resposta seu comentario. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get Latest Version (Recursive)**

Ele vai atualizar todos os arquivos do seu projeto para a versão mais recente.

**Check Out for Edit**

Este vai informar ao TFS que você está trabalhando neste arquivo, isto pode gerar um "Lock" no arquivo para evitar que outros trabalhem nele.

**Shelve Pending Changes**

você deve usar este quando quiser salvar ou compartilhar alguma alteração incompleta, seja por que precisa trabalhar em outra atividade, passar a atividade para outro ou você ainda não teve tempo de testar e alguém precisa executar ele.